# How to separate character and number from string in c program

Tags: c

For example, I want to separate the string "0013subdivision" into 0013 (as an integer that can do addition, subtraction, etc. not char) and subdivision (as a char itself) in the given string.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char location[10]; /* for the input with number and letter */
char x;
int house[10]; /* for the integer that will be separated from the string */
int main()
{
    printf("Input: ");
    scanf ("%s", &location[x]);

    x=0
    for (x=0; location[x]!='\0'; x++ );
    return 0;
}
```

Based on my research, the code `atoi` is used to convert the converted value back to int (if I'm not mistaken) but I don't know when to place the function.

Comment: What's wrong with using `*scanf`?! `%d` for the decimal(?) integer... `%s` for the string part

Comment: Also, no need for an `int` array to read an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in the code is

```
   scanf ("%s", &location[x]);
```

Where you did not impose any limit on the *scanning*. An input like `0013subdivision` will cause out of bound memory access leading to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Always limit the input size with the length modifier, like, for an array defined  as

```
 char location[10]
```

use the conversion specification like

```
 scanf ("%9s", location);   // (i) one element saved for terminating null
                            // (ii) the array name decays to the pointer to 1st element
                            //in case of an argument to a function call.
```

Then, you don't need an integer array to store the extracted integer. A *singular* variable would suffice.

---

However, i'd like to suggest a much robust way:

- read the user input using [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)
- then, scan the input using [`sscanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) and appropriate conversion specifier, like `%4d%9s` or alike.

Answer (score 1):

`location` is `char array`, if you are reading as string use only `%s` with string name only, `index` not required.

`scanf ("%s", &location[x]);` --> `scanf ("%s", location);`

After separating only `int` from `char array` you need to store one `int` value into `house`.

`int house[10]` --> `int house`.

Here is the code for extracting only int from string :

```
char location[10]; /* for the input with number and letter */
int x;
int house = 0 ; /* for the integer that will be separated from the string */
int main()
{
        printf("Input: ");
        //scanf ("%s", &location[x]);
        scanf ("%s", location);

                for (x=0; location[x]!='\0'; x++ ) {
                        if(location[x]>='0' && location[x]<='9') {
                                house =(house * 10) + (location[x]-48);
                        }
                }
                        printf("int part = %d \n",house);


        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The most correct way to do this is to use the `strto...` family of functions from stdlib.h. For example:

  ```
  printf("%ld\n", strtol(str, NULL, 10));
  ```
- The `atoi` family of functions should never be used for any purpose, since they have broken error handling and can be 100% replaced by the `strto...` functions.
- You could use the scanf family of functions but they are needlessly slow and notoriously dangerous, so I don't really see the point of using them here.

If you are interested in implementing the actual copying manually, for learning purposes, it is fairly trivial:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  const char str[] = "0013subdivision";
  char number_part [sizeof(str)];
  char letter_part [sizeof(str)];
  size_t i;

  for(i=0; str[i]!='\0' && isdigit(str[i]); i++) // find where the letters start
  {}

  memcpy(number_part, &str[0], i);             // copy digit part
  number_part[i] = '\0';                       // append null terminator
  memcpy(letter_part, &str[i], sizeof(str)-i); // copy letter part + null term

  puts(number_part);
  puts(letter_part);
  printf("%ld\n", strtol(str, NULL, 10));
}
```

If the string is a run-time variable, you have to use `strlen(str)+1` instead of `sizeof()`.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtol`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) converts string to number and also gives you back the character it stopped on, i.e. first character after number.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  const char* const input = "0013subdivision";
  const char* string;
  const long number = strtol(input, &string, 10);

  printf("Number: %ld String: '%s'\n", number, string);
  // Number: 13 String: 'subdivision'
  return 0;
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/SphericalImpracticalTinamou